# Почему очистка PictureBox не происходит сразу?

Tags: c#

Вот скажите у меня есть событие, что при нажатии на кнопку "Без Сохранения" PictureBox создает чистый лист для рисования (м.б я не правильно выразился). Я использую этот код

```
Graphisc graphics1;

graphics1.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor );
```

Но он очищает PictureBox, только после того, как вы начали рисовать новый рисунок, а не сразу. Где у меня допущена ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может это?

```
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
```

Comment: Ага все подошло! Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
Graphisc graphics1;
graphics1.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor );
pictureBox1.Repaint();
pictureBox1.Update();
```

Comment: Ошибка

Ошибка 1 "System.Drawing.Graphics" не содержит определения для "update" и не был найден метод расширения "update", принимающий тип "System.Drawing.Graphics" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку) D:\dima\Новый год - копия\Новый год\Form2.cs 83 23 Новый год

Comment: в С# все методы начинаеются с заглавной буквы, это во-первых, а во-вторых у класса [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) нету методов ``Repaint`` и ``Update``

Comment: Update надо вызвать у PictureBox

Comment: @Spectre прав, я поспешил, надо апдейтить и репейнить поле по которому рисуешь